# Get Bitmap Thumbnail from NReco FFMpegConverter in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, ffmpeg

I have implemented the FFMpegConverter to get a thumbnail from a video in ASP.NET and this is my code:

```
var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
//The 1st parameter specifies the location of the video, the 2nd specifies the location where the thumbnail is to be saved
ffMpeg.GetVideoThumbnail(Convert.ToString("C:\\Users\\Earthling\\Videos\\video.mp4"), Server.MapPath("~/videos/videoupload.jpg"));
```

The above code works fine. My question is, how do I get a Bitmap object out of the output instead of saving it in the Project Folder?

Basically, remove/replace this line of code:

```
Server.MapPath("~/videos/videoupload.jpg")
```

And get a Bitmap Object output instead of saving it in the Project folder.

Any ideas guys?